# How can we get [adaptivePosition] property from nativeElement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get an adaptivePosition property from a native element.

Tried with el.nativeElement.getAttribute('adaptivePosition') but returns null. It should return value of adaptivePosition

Comment: What do you mean adaptive position? relative? absolute?

Comment: For ngx-bootstrap popover we use this adaptivePosition to determine the position of the popover based on element. Please refer this https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/7.1.2/#/popover#adaptive-position

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
el.nativeElement.getAttribute('[adaptivePosition]')
```

**If you defined that in html part it'll do. unless you cannot use nativeElement!**

Comment: it returns null

Comment: Yes, I defined in html part and then trying to get from nativeElement and still it returns null

Comment: HTML: 
<button type="button" placement="bottom" [adaptivePosition]="true" class="btn btn-warning"> Popover</button>

TS:
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this._elementRef2.nativeElement.getAttribute('[adaptivePosition]'))
  }

Comment: Does this show your button in console? `console.log(this._elementRef2.nativeElement)`

Comment: Yes, it shows 
<button type="button" placement="bottom" class="btn btn-warning"></button>